# JavaScript "return false" from onkeypress handler

Tags: javascript

I used code in the below method to block my keyboard and it worked for me.

```
<asp:textbox id="t1" onkeypress="return false;" />
```

Now I want to add some more for for it and I tired to do the same using extra code as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
fuction disablekeys()
{
return false;
}
</script>
<asp:textbox id="t1" onkeypress="disablekeys();" />
```

But this code is not working. Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to return the value returned by `disablekeys`:

```
<asp:textbox id="t1" onkeypress="return disablekeys();" />
```

Your new `onkeypress` handler currently ignores this value.

Comment: I also just noticed that `function` is spelled wrong in your code (fuction).

Comment: Another simple thing that's easy for me to overlook.